# Style applied from other div

Tags: html, css

I have div with different names on 2 different pages. I applied a background color to the `textarea` on hover and on focus in `div id="contact"`.

```
<style>
     #contact input:hover,textarea:hover    {   background-color:#CFF;  }
     #contact input:focus,textarea:focus    {   background-color:#CCF;  }
 </style>

<div id="contact">
    <li>
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea class="required" name="message"></textarea>
     </li>
</div>
```

The textarea in a differently named div on a different page is displaying the background on hover and focus though I don't want it to.

```
<div id="wants">
    <li>
        <label>Additional information - the more you tell us, the better we can help.</label>
        <textarea name="addlinfo" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
    </li>
</div>
```

Dreamweaver's Code Navigator is showing the styles created for "contact" are applied to "wants". I can't figure out why. The textarea is the only element affected on "wants". There are inputs on the page and are not affected. Will someone please explain to this noob?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need

```
#contact input:hover, #contact textarea:hover {}
#contact input:focus, #contact textarea:focus {}
```

instead of your current selector.

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rxL54/)

Your current style selects *any* textarea, regardless of its parents.